# Laptop Intel HD graphics not detected, only ATI is found

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, intel, vga

I'm using Dell n5010 with dual Intel HD VGA and ATI radeon VGA. I have installed fglrx and amdcccle. But linux doesn't seems to detect my intel VGA but it detects ATI card.

inxi -G gives following output

```
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Madison [Mobility Radeon HD 5650/5750 / 6530M/6550M] 
           X.Org: 1.15.1 driver: fglrx Resolution: 1366x768@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: AMD Mobility Radeon HD 5000 Series GLX Version: 4.3.12798 - CPC 13.35.1005
```

lspci -v | grep -i vga gives the following

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Madison [Mobility Radeon HD 5650/5750 / 6530M/6550M] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

and mesa-utils is already the newest version

What can I do to get Intel grapics  working? thanks.

Comment: same issue here, got any solution?

Comment: nope. I couldn't find any solution too